# Understanding Higher Kinded Type Function

Tags: scala

Given `Parent` and `Result` Algebraic Data Types:

```
sealed trait Parent
case object Kid extends Parent

sealed trait Result[A <: Parent]
case class ResultImpl[A <: Parent](x: A) extends Result[A]
```

I then wrote:

```
def general[A <: Parent, F[_]](x: A, f: A => F[A]): F[A] = 
  f(x)
```

However, I'm not sure how to call `general` to get an output of type, `ResultImpl[Kid.type]`.

I attempted:

```
scala> general(Kid, ResultImpl.apply)
<console>:19: error: inferred kinds of the type arguments (Kid.type,ResultImpl) do not conform to the expected kinds of the type parameters (type A,type F).
ResultImpl's type parameters do not match type F's expected parameters:
type A's bounds <: Parent are stricter than type _'s declared bounds >: Nothing <: Any
       general(Kid, ResultImpl.apply)
       ^
<console>:19: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Kid.type
 required: A
       general(Kid, ResultImpl.apply)
               ^
<console>:19: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Nothing => ResultImpl[Nothing]
 required: A => F[A]
       general(Kid, ResultImpl.apply)
                               ^
```

How can I do that with the `general` function?

Comment: It would be more readable and convenient for someone that wants to answer if you used paste-mode in the REPL and copy/pasted that into there. Cleaning up the `|` bars from the REPL becomes tedious.

Comment: Thanks, m-z - updated. I'll keep that in mind in my future posts.

Comment: @m-z It's not necessary to clean up VBARs. If you paste the transcript, including random junk output, REPL takes the lines with prompts (`scala>` and `|`) as input. That is, paste but not in `:paste` mode, just paste at the prompt. The leading prompt says "I am a transcript".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify that your `_` is `<: Parent` as well, because `A` is. Also you might want to split arguments into two groups for the compiler to infer `A` correctly:

```
def general[A <: Parent, F[_ <: Parent]](x: A)(f: A => F[A]): F[A] =
              f(x)
```

Then the next works as expected:

```
general(Kid)(ResultImpl(_))
```

Comment: Thank you. Out of curiosity, is there no way to use the `A` in the type constraint, `A <: Parent` within the other type constraint, `F[...]`?

Comment: @KevinMeredith That's correct. You could write `def general[A <: Parent, F[_ <: A]]` which actually may be even more appropriate than my variant.